# R ggplot2 theme_set colorblind or dichromat color?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, colors

In R ggplot2 are you able to `theme_set(theme_grey() + "colorblind_function"` at the top of the code rather than adding `+ scale_color_colorblind()` to each plot?

Some ggthemes I've used in the past:

```
show_col(colorblind_pal()(8))
show_col(tableau_color_pal("colorblind10")(10))
show_col(dichromat_pal("BluetoOrange.10")(10))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the default color scale by overwriting `scale_colour_discrete` (and similarly for `fill`, for continuous scales, etc.):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)

scale_colour_discrete <- scale_colour_colorblind

ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color = Species)) + 
  geom_point(size = 2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Claus. I think I like the dichromat categorical 12 colors the best but don't like the order the colors are in. This is how I figured out how to change the order.

```
show_col(dichromat_pal("Categorical.12")(12))

dichromat.fun <- function(...)
{
  discrete_scale("colour", "colorblind", dichromat_pal("Categorical.12"), 
                 ...)
}

my.dichromat.pal <- function(n){
  new.dichro.order.pal <- c("#664CFF", "#33FF00", "#FF8000", "#E61A33", "#FFFF33", "#FF99BF", "#1AB2FF", "#CCBFFF", "#B2FF8C", "#FFBF80", "#FFFF99", "#A6EDFF")
  new.dichro.order.pal[seq_len(n)]
}

my.dichromat.fun <- function(...){
  discrete_scale("colour", "colorblind", my.dichromat.pal, 
                 ...)
}


a.df <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12), b=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1))

scale_colour_discrete <- dichromat.fun

ggplot(a.df, aes(a, b, color=factor(a))) + geom_point(size=5)

scale_colour_discrete <- my.dichromat.fun

ggplot(a.df, aes(a, b, color=factor(a))) + geom_point(size=5)
```

[image: original order]

[image: my order]